# Make Rails Through Associations Render UNDER what They're Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, so I have this in my serializer and model:

```
class Review< ApplicationRecord
    has_one :gamesection
        has_many :releases, through: :gamesection
        has_one :cover, through: :gamesection
        has_many :otherpics, through: :cover, through: :gamesection
```

But the problem is that it renders like

```
Review
->gamesection
->release
->cover
->otherpics
```

While I want it to be

```
Review
->gamesection
--->release
--->cover
--->otherpics
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: change the css margins in your view so that it appears the way you want

Comment: What does your serializer look like? What do you use to render the content and what does the view look like?

Comment: My serializer is the same as the first code clip above, and the view just has everything right under the Review, rather than nested under other parts

Answer (score 0):

You should have below in your rails serializer.

```
# /app/serializers/review_serializer.rb
class ReviewSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :title,
  has_one :gamesection
end

# /app/serializers/gamesection_serializer.rb
class GamesectionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
            
  has_many :releases
  has_one  :cover
  has_many :otherpics 
end
```